# How to split string with comma (,) and wrap the result by single quotes (')

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am trying split string in javascript. How to split string value append with' :

```
Mystring='123,234,345'
```

My expected output is like :

```
output='123','234','345'
```

Comment: what is the expected data type of `output`?

Comment: `my expected output is like` - which is not possible

Comment: Do you mean `output=['123', '234', '345']` ?

Comment: Your title says you want to split the string with a space, yet the code implies a comma. Also, the fact you already know the word 'split' means you should have been able to research this yourself in a matter of seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** method :

```
var output = Mystring.split(',');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var Mystring='123,234,345';
var output = Mystring.split(',');

console.log(output)
```

**Join array items using single quote `'` using [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) :**

```js
var Mystring='123,234,345';
var output = Mystring.split(',');
console.log(output)

var output_with_qoutes = "'" + output.join("','") + "'";
console.log(output_with_qoutes);
```

Comment: Hello i can split the string.But how to append '' for each value

Comment: Hi, the output in your OP `'123','234','345'`, is an invalid representation :( because it has n type for it it will return `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`.

Comment: But i want to split , value and append ' to string

Answer (score 2):

```js
let result = '123,234,345'.split(',').map(s => `'${s}'`).join(',');

console.dir(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `split` in native JS

```
Mystring.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first split it using `split()` and then `iterate` over it using `each()` to make it in your expected format.

```js
var Mystring = '123,234,345';
var output = Mystring.split(',');
var finalOutput = "";
$.each(output, function(index) {
  finalOutput += "'" + output[index] + "',";
});

console.log(finalOutput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hello thank you.But i want to use single quotes.like '123','234',''345'

Comment: @vithika updated answer. Just you need to use ' instead of ". Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Mystring='123,234,345';
var arr = Mystring.split(',');
var output = "";
for (i=0; i<(arr.length-1); i++)
  {
    output = output + "'" + arr[i] + "'," ;
  }
output = output + "'" + arr[arr.length-1] + "'" ;
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and wrap the string in single quotes.

```js
var myString = '123,234,345',
    result = '\'' + myString.replace(/,/g, '\',\'') + '\'';

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just use double quotes and get rid of all the noisey `\'`